# Drupal won't output echo as anonymous

Tags: php, drupal-7

I'm having a weird problem with Drupal 7.

For debugging purposes i found out that if i'm not logged in, i can't see any echo's on my drupal page when developing my module.

I'm not able to use drupal_set_message(), or create / read cookies.

Any idea why this is?

**EDIT:**
All users including anonymous is able to see the node. I'm working on a module that is shown on the node (it has some form elements etc.).

I tried to set some default text depending on a cookie was set or not. It works perfectly as long as your are logged in, but once you are an anonymous user, it doesn't read/write the cookie.

I tried to debug this by putting in a few echo's and drupal_set_message(), but they are only shown when I'm logged in, and doesnt show for anonymous users. I can't figure out why this is.

Comment: Do you mean that you don't have access to the page created from your module? If that is the case, did you check anonymous users have permission to see that page?

Comment: Can you show us your code?  It is much easier to fix code that you can see.  Provide an example that allows people to replicate your problem, and the answers will likely be numerous and useful.

Comment: Added an EDIT to main post for clarification.

Comment: I agree with @ghoti: Show the code you are using, and you will get better answers. Differently, you are going to get generic answers that could be useful, or less useful.

Comment: Also, for Drupal configuration issues like this, you may find a more receptive audience at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

If it is secure to display debugging messages to non-authenticated users (e.g.: your site is not accessible from internet), you can do this:

- install [devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module
- enable "Access developer information" in permissions table (example.com/admin/people/permissions)
- use `dpm` or [other functions](http://ratatosk.net/drupal/tutorials/debugging-drupal.html) to print your logs.

But if non-authenticaed users can't access the specific content due to permissions to that content, you must enable permissions to display that content.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to disable caching for anonymous users here: admin/config/development/performance

On a dev system, it's probably a good idea to disable all the bandwidth optimization checkboxes as well.